# Java 11 HttpClient request to HTTPS resource via proxy

Tags: java, https, proxy, httpclient, apache-httpclient-5.x

It is necessary to execute REST requests through a proxy. Several HTTP proxy servers are available, protected with Basic Authentication. Java 16 is used.

An example of a fully working request when accessing HTTP resources:

```
var proxySettings = new ProxySettings("http", "proxy.ip.address", proxy.port, "userName", "password");

var request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(new URI("http://tv-games.ru")).build();

HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .proxy(ProxySelector.of(new InetSocketAddress(proxySettings.getUri(), proxySettings.port())))
        .authenticator(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(proxySettings.userName(), proxySettings.getPasswordArray());
            }
        }).build();
HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

System.out.println("Body: " + response.body());
System.out.println("Code: " + response.statusCode());
```

This is an object that carries information about the proxy server:

```
public record ProxySettings(String scheme, String hostname, int port, String userName, String password) {

        public char[] getPasswordArray() {
            return password.toCharArray();
        }

        public String getUri() {
            return scheme + "://" + hostname;
        }
    }
```

When requesting an HTTPS resource, for example, https://yandex.ru, I get the error
407 (Proxy Authentication Required).

I am currently using an Apache HttpClient 5 based workaround:

```
HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("https", "yandex.ru");
HttpHost proxyHost = new HttpHost(proxySettings.scheme(), proxySettings.hostname(), proxySettings.port());

//Create the HttpGet request object
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("/");
httpget.setConfig(RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxyHost).build());

//Create the CloseableHttpClient
CredentialsStore credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(proxySettings.hostname(), proxySettings.port()),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxySettings.userName(), proxySettings.getPasswordArray()));

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();

//Get the result
CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse = client.execute(targetHost, httpget);
System.out.println("Body: " + EntityUtils.toString(closeableHttpResponse.getEntity()));
System.out.println("Code: " + httpResponse.code());

EntityUtils.consume(closeableHttpResponse.getEntity());
```

However, Apache HttpClient dependencies are quite heavyweight, I really want to stay within the framework of pure Java.

Is it possible to use the built-in HttpClient to access HTTPS resources through a proxy?